# cmake - how to set path to CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to install this https://github.com/NVlabs/ssn_superpixels but get the error below at the step `cmake ..`

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "caffe" in directory /home/haziq/ASTAR/scripts/ssn_superpixels/lib/video_prop_networks/lib/caffe/src/caffe
```

I then tried to search for the library and found a `libcublas.so.9.1` and `libcublas.so.9.1.85`.

```
(base) haziq@mdeep:~/ASTAR/scripts/ssncaffe$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.9.1
libcublas.so.9.1     libcublas.so.9.1.85
```

How do I now tell CMake the path to the CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY? The command

```
cmake .. CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.9.1
```

does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cmake .. -DCUDA_cublas_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.9.1
```